# Potential Firestore offline get data bug

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I try to get data from a document offline and I get VERY different times loading the same document. The document is one of five in a collection (not many documents).
The document contains maybe 10 fields and 3 arrays fairly large maybe but not close to 1 mb limit.

This is how I tested this.

Turn on airplane mode

1. Load the same document.
2. Save the same document as is with no change.
3. Waiting for maybe 10-30 seconds
4. Repeat

This is the time output:

1. 5.301s
2. 2.378s
3. 35.892s
4. 65.456s
5. 55.123s
6. 23.831s

Every time I close the application even if I keep airplane mode so cache is kept, and don't keep the activity and do these steps again it is always fast again in the start and turns slower.

What I have found is that when it takes so long, The document is collected right after this:

`2021-08-27 20:45:29.109 W/Firestore: (23.0.3) [WatchStream]: (XXXXXX) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Unable to resolve host firestore.googleapis.com, cause=java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "firestore.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname`

So I think it has something to do with this:

`Firestore: (23.0.3) [ExponentialBackoff]: Backing off for 76823 ms (base delay: 60000 ms, delay with jitter: 76849 ms, last attempt: 26 ms ago)`

More info:

- There are no snapshot listeners connected to the document.
- The data in appInfo is: 6.68MB
- The cache in appInfo is: 115KB